Screenshot of the Week #128
This contest is over.
previous contest | next contest
Hello and welcome to the 128th edition of the Screenshot of the Week!
To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! Daemons's screenshot from dead-cells won with 9 upvotes!


To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
Stack Exchange’s Code of Conduct still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.
How long will the contest run?
We will accept submissions for a week, until November 11, 2024, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.
After the end of the second week, at November 18, 2024, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

No Theme
There is no theme this week.
As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a question of its own.  Additionally, there is the hall of fame you can check out that contains all the previous contest winners.

Aloy at it again, fighting machines in horizon-zero-dawn’s PS5 remaster


I think I like her hair

I see Aloy, I upvote <3

@pinckerman This is my 4th time playing the story (even platinumed it on the PS4)

@Wondercricket I still have to play Burning shores but I can totally relate, I'll purchase the remastered as soon as it gets discounted

@pinckerman not sure which version you have, but if you already own the digital edition for the PS4, you can get the remaster for $10. That’s what I did

@Wondercricket I have the physical one

@Wondercricket I have almost plantinumed it on PC. great game

Ocean on Regis III
the-invincible


Dusk in valheim


Playing hide and seek with the sun, are we?

Relaxing sunset mihenroad in final-fantasy-10


I think I recognise that passage. It's in the recorded message from Yuna, right?

@Clockwork that's right. There yuna recordet here the last will/message for her guardians.

Massive doink* incoming!
Tonberry from final-fantasy-xiii.

*: "Doink" is the noise the knife makes in Final Fantasy VIII when the Tonberry summon lands a hit against an enemy: https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/finalfantasy/images/0/00/FFVIII_Chef%27s_Knife.PNG/revision/latest?cb=20191115173033

In every part of final fantasy deadly creature.

@nobody The first time I met one in Final Fantasy VI, I was severely underleveled and I didn't understand why it kept one hit killing me with its blue orbs. Turns out that attack damage depends on how many steps I took since the beginning of the game, and since I like to roam around a lot...

In fantasy 10 it depends on how much enemies you killed.

Well, in 7, with the right setup and strategy, you can easily beat them without taking any damage at all.

You always bow to Grimm. Always.

hollow-knight

And here I was wondering if I was the only one who bowed to him when he bowed.

Now I feel like replaying Hollow Knight. Again.

@Clockwork Now I feel like finally 112%-ing the game on my first play through (I’m already at around 102%).

Is this an old screenshot or are you still in the process of going through Godhome?

@Clockwork Still going through it. Only things left to finish in the game for percentages are to beat godhome, the pantheons, and kill the radiance.

Good luck. The Pantheon of Hallownest took me 5 attempts, but then again I died countless times against the Pure Vessel.

So relatable. I have only the last pantheon left, and I really don't know if I can beat it.

@pinckerman It's very achievable when you know you are capable of dealing with each boss individually, really. You can go at the bottom of Godhome to train individually against each boss if you want to make sure you're ready. But after going through everything, I usually got so stressed up I died to the final boss twice.

@Clockwork yea I know that, my problem is that I'm not consistent enough with Pure Vessel, and I really don't want to spend one hour just to die against him :') let alone beat Absolute Radiance...

I just returned to Hollow Knight after 28 months without playing. It's really something...

@Clockwork little update: I trained a lot with Pure Vessel, but I definitely underestimated Markoth :')

@pinckerman Markoth will always be terrifying. Made the mistake of first trying to beat him with all upgrades. Still haven’t done it.

@pinckerman The secret with Markoth is patience. It gets dangerous when he starts wearing down your patience and you try to nail him down. When I feel like it gets too annoying, I just dodge and hit from time to time with charge dashed attacks. Patience also works well with the Blood Hive trinket which heals you 1 shield if you avoid taking any more damage for a while.

@Clockwork my idea is to build up souls on phase 1, and then destroy him with abyss shreiks on phase 2, but two spinning shields and homing nails are really too annoying. There's a well deserved place in hell for the guy who designed that thing.

@pinckerman I was looking through my screenshots from 2 years ago, and it looks like past version of me had written an advice for dealing with him: if he's too annoying, keep dodging all the swords he's shooting at you until he stops and starts spinning his shield. If he's in an easily reachable position, wait him out and start charging your nail. When he's nearly stopped (when he retracted the spinning shield) and is about to resume throwing swords, dash towards him and release the charged attack. That's the safest moment to land that charged attack (I use dashed because it has bigger range).

@Clockwork I managed to beat Pure Vessel and Absolute Radiance, so I finally get the platinum and I can play something else! :D

@pinckerman Good job! Now you just have to wait for Silksong!

@pinckerman Nice job. In a few weeks/months, you may feel the urge to replay Hollow Knight again x)

@DaemonsMercy sure! but give me some rest LOL

Another beautiful day in the jungle as the sun rises in minecraft.


Such a square sun  ☀️

How I learned to put Lightning Rods over my Villagers in minecraft-java-edition


Yep, lightning does a bunch of random things: Villager→witch, charged creeper, skeleton horses, zombie pig, mooshroom colour, turtle bowl drop, … And it goes some distance through blocks, too. That is one of the reasons why I have a gigantic map art above my base!

@FabianRöling I've just learnt that turtles killed by lightning drop their bowl, the more you know

@FabianRöling I was aware that Lightning turned villagers into witches, i was just thinking that them being behind solid blocks would prevent that, but seeing my villager house suddenly full of witches after a Thunderstorm taught me otherwise. Lightning Rods really are the perfect solution, as they cover a radius of 128 blocks around them, which is quite a lot. You just gotta have no flammable blocks right next to them.

When you lose so bad that the game rejects you ...

This happened to me, in overwatch-2, after losing a clash match in less than 2 minutes, in Hanaoka.
